# What does 「ならないようにする」 mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does 「ならないようにする」 mean?

> しかし、建物を地震に強くしたり、火事にならないようにすると、亡くなる人を２３００人に減らすことができると言っています。([source](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10013967481000/k10013967481000.html))

Comment: I would translate the entire to say "it is said, however,  that if buildings  are strengthened against earthquakes and made so that they will not catch on fire, the number of people who die could be reduced by 2300."

Comment: It says "reduced to 2300", not "reduced by 2300".

Comment: @TokyoNagoya, Thanks! By the way, how would you say "reduced by 2300"?

Comment: @virmaior, this is just a guess, but 「2300で減らす」?

Comment: @hatsuyuki How about just 2300人減らす?

Answer (score 3):

火事にならないようにする = avoid fire accident

Answer (score 3):

roughly, "make buildings so that they will not catch on fire"

Answer (score 3):

Xようにする is, more generally, "make it so that X"/"do something to (try to) make X happen" (or not happen, in this case).