# Which conjugation is this? 吸わないようにしています

Tags: conjugations

> マスクをして、花粉を鼻から吸わないようにしています

It has the general meaning of "they use masks so that they don't breathe pollen through their noses". My question is about the

> 吸わないようにしています

part. Which conjugation is this? 吸わない comes from 吸う (to breathe in). What about ようにしています?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13839/9749

Answer (score 1):

吸わ(未然形 of verb 吸う) + ない(auxiliary verb which means "negative") + ように(連用形 of auxiliary verb ようだ which means "analogy" + し(連用形 of verb する) + て(postpositional particle) + い(連用形 of subsidiary verb いる) + ます(auxiliary verb which means "politeness")

And て + いる is used together as one word ている.

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to answer a beginner-ish question with the Japanese grammar terms. They split words up too much. Using the simpler Western terms may be more helpful. E.g. 吸わない is the negative form of 吸う and して comes from する

Comment: Really? But medium and advanced Japanese learners may want the explanation in detail.